Vandermonde system in a Banach space
Let $V$ be a Banach space and $T\colon V \to V$ a bounded operator. Assume that we have a countable infinite sequence $v_1,v_2,v_3,\ldots$ of eigenvectors of $T$ with pairwise distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots$ ($Tv_i = \lambda_iv_i$). Assume even further that the series $\sum \|v_i\|$ is absolutely convergent, so that the element $$v = \sum_{i=1}^\infty v_i$$ exists.
Consider now the two closed subspaces of $V$:
$$W_1 = \overline{\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty \langle v_i\rangle }$$
$$W_2 = \overline{\bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty \langle T^i v\rangle }$$
We clearly have $W_2 \subseteq W_1$, but my intuition from the finite-dimensional case tells me that they should in fact be equal. To prove that $W_1 = W_2$ would be a Banach-space analog of inverting a Vandermonde-type infinite matrix. I've tried to estimate the "difference" between $W_1$ and the finite-dimensional spaces $\langle v,Tv,T^2v,\ldots, T^k v\rangle$ but it didn't get me very far. I imagine this situation might be quite common, and this might have been studied already. Is there any reference for this problem?
I am mostly interested in the non-archimedean case, in particular where $V$ is a $\mathbb{Q}_p$-vector space, but I'm not sure if this is relevat to the problem at hand.
